# Where did the idea of using X to mean 'Extra' first start?

Tags: etymology

It makes sense, but I'm curious as to how long ago it started and where.

Comment: Are you kidding me?  How would you abbreviate "extra large"?

Answer (score 1):

may it have started in 1827 when in malt liquor XX denoted "double quality" and XXX "strongest quality" :

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=X&allowed_in_frame=0

Answer (score 0):

- XL (extra large) dates to a 1950 Massachusetts newspaper.
- XXL (extra, extra large) dates to a 1952 New York newspaper.